# How can this get route be manipulated to get access my other parts of the server?

Tags: node.js, express

**Can this be manipulated to get other parts of server?**

```
const downloadRoot = './uploads/'
app.get("/uploads/:id", (req, res) => {
    const fullPath = path.resolve(path.join(downloadRoot, req.params.id));
    res.download(fullPath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ll give you an example with db models.

You have index.js in folder /models with

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const db = {};

db.mongoose = mongoose;

db.token = require("./token.model");
db.user = require("./user.model");

module.exports = db;
```

Then you can get access (not manipulate /models/index.js). Otherwise you can modify instance in each .js

Example in app.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

const db = require("./db/models");

db.mongoose
    .connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        createIndexes: true
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Successfully connect to MongoDB.");
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error("Connection error", err);
        process.exit();
    });
```

module.exports does this